# Animation conflict causes container to over-scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I have prepared the following example to showcase the behaviour I am struggling with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-sun-2h94tg?file=/src/CollapsableCard.tsx

The brief is this:

Click a container to open it. That container should scroll into view **smoothly**, and also expand, while the previously expanded container should collapse.

If not scrolled smoothly, everything work as expected. However, if scrolled smoothly (as in the sandbox), you can see that subsequent containers' scrolling overshoots the parent.
I have surmized that this happens because of a race between the smooth scroll animation, and the collapse animation.

In essence, the selected container scrolls into view, THEN the previous container collapses, pulling the selected container up with it, effectively making it overscroll.

My "solution" is therefore to wait for the collapse animation with this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused) {
    setTimeout(() => ref.current?.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" }));
  }
}, [isFocused]);
```

This, however, creates quite a jarring user experience, as the user clicks a container and sees it expand, but then waits for it to scroll.

The solution I'm looking for is to do both at the same time, but to somehow, perhaps, lock the parent onto the currently focused child while it's animating. I would like the newly selected container to scroll into view and stay thee while the other container is collapsing.